# jquery ui - making dialogs more "dynamic"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that uses multiple dialogs for different things. Some dialogs may have buttons that others do not while other may need to be a different height than another... All of them have a set of params that will not change. My question, can I have a default like:

```
$('.someElement').dialog({
   width: 999,
   show: 'slide',
   hide: 'slide',
   ETC: 'some other option' 
});
```

and use it for all of my dialogs, then pass buttons or height to it dynamically when I open a dialog? It just seems wrong to have something like the above for every dialog I need...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`"option"` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-option) (which takes an object, of the same format), like this:

```
$('.someElement').dialog({
   width: 999,
   show: 'slide',
   hide: 'slide',
   autoOpen: false
}); 
$('.someElement').dialog('option', {
  buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
  height: 400
}).dialog('open');
```

[You can see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AVn4b/), this just sets whatever options you want before calling the [`open` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-open).

Comment: Your syntax is a little off. I got this working but am failing to get multiple params to work:   $('.dialog').dialog('option', 
   'buttons', {
    'Ok': function() { 
     $(this).dialog("close"); 
   }
  }).dialog('open'); - is it possible to add multiple "options" here?

Comment: @mike - You're right, I missed a `}` to close the `buttons: {` in there, answer is updated and added a demo you can play with.

Comment: I see now... an object. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could create a wrapper function for this:

```
function showDialog(target, options){
   options.width = 999;
   options.show = 'slide';
   options.hide = 'slide';

   $(target).dialog(options);
}
```

And then you would just call the function when you want to create a dialog. You could even get fancy and turn it into a jQuery plugin if you really want to...